# Failed to generate channel configuration transaction... (Faild to create a channel while setting up the Fabric test network)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to create a channel after bringing up the network successfully. I have used the script

```
./network.sh createChannel
```

However, I got this error explained in this screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJGzL.png)

Any help?